# Convert regular text to array using notepad++

Tags: php, arrays, notepad++

i am trying to use notepad++ to select a new line and replace it with this " ','  ", so that i can use it in PHP as an array and then work on it, but i dont know what regular expression to use in the search and replace form.

Below is what i have

```
Tunneller
Turf Accountant
Turkey Farmer
Turner
Tutor
Typesetter
Typewriter Engineer
Typist..
```

[image: and it continues like that for over 1000+ lines of text]

and you want to arrive at something like this - array like syntax to feed into my php document.

```
$array =  ['Tunneller','Turf','Accountant','TurkeyFarmer','Turner','Tutor','Typesetter','Typewriter Engineer','Typist']
```

thanks.

Comment: Can you read the file into php, seperate each line, and add it  into an array position?

Comment: okay, let me rephrase, it is actually longer than that.. about 1157 lines, let me paste a screen shot, so people can easily understand that i cant be doing what you just said for over 1157 lines. there has to be a way out.

Answer (score 5):

To turn your input into a quoted, comma separated list (transform ALL lines from `text` to `'text',`)

- Go to menu *Search* then *Replace...*.
- Make sure *Search Mode* is `Regular Expression` and `. matches newline` is NOT checked.

*Find what:* `.*`

*Replace with:* `'$0',`

- `Replace All`

Then you just need to manually add `$array =  [` and the closing `];`.

Personally I would do it in PHP like this or something similar to read the file lines into an array:

```
$array = file('/path/to/file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

If you really need to print it as an array definition for some reason:

```
echo '<pre>$array = ' . var_export($array, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: going through all this wouldnt be necessary, notepad++ does it seamlessly. its not needed at runtime, just trying to populate the database with the entries, thats all.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Hit <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>

**2.** Activate the extended option

**3.** Put in search `\r\n` that means carriage return and new line

**4.** And put in replace `,`